# Redirecting using @Url.Action in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url.action

I have a scenario, where I have to redirect using hyper link in MVC and there I have to add action name, controller name & object name. When I try to enter the object name, It is not finding that object name. How to get the object name in Url.Action?

My Url in UI has to look like this: localhost:00/area/Controller/ActionMethod/ItemId.

Here I need help how to add the Itemid in `Url.Action`.

Comment: href="@Url.Action("ActionMethodName", "Controller", new { area="AreaName"} now I have this (localhost:00/area/Controller/ActionMethod), I need to add one more itemid and go to that url(localhost:00/area/Controller/ActionMethod/ItemId) .

Comment: Yes, but itemid is not finding.

Answer (score 0):

`@Url.Action` is used inside `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Controller", new { itemId = ItemId })" >LinkName</a>
```

Comment: Here when I enter itemid , it is not finding.

Comment: Use same parameter name `string=itemId` in your Action method.

Comment: I am sorry to ask this, but Can we know from a view to which controller the view belongs.

Comment: Of course, You can see in `@Url.Action` 2nd parameter is the controller name.

Comment: Thank You ! I verified in the controller under that action method it has a parameter named string itemid , but when I use it in @Url.Action it is saying "View does not contain a definition for itemid"

Comment: When I right click on the view there is an option : go to controller then it is taking me to a different controller than the one I am using in @Url.Action.

Comment: Not yet solved but it helped me to identify the controller.

Comment: Your question is to add ItemId in `@Url.Action` Is it still not solved? When you run it and click on the link, it does not redirect to related Action method?

Comment: I am not able to add ItemId in @Url.Action.There are 3 views(view 1, 2 & 3), View 1 is related to Action Method, View 2(when I right click on View 2 , getting a message unable to find a matching controller) is calling in View 3. Now I am adding ItemId in View3, it is not finding ItemId. View 1 has ItemId. But the hyper link text was in View3. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Not clear. Kindly show that `@Url.Action` as a whole and Action method in controller related to that action link.

Comment: you can pass the Itemid to view3. If you face issue, show the code